# select dropdown shows last value first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lit-element

I have two four `dropdown`s, second `dropdown` selected and if I select first `dropdown`, second `dropdown` populates the value but shows last element first instead of first

```js
   sample data get the dropdown values
   var countrydata ={
    countries:[{
        "country_code": "TH",
        "country_name": "Thailand",
        "currency_from": [
            "THB",
            "USD"
        ],
        "currency_to": [
            "THB"
        ],
        "popular_to": [
            "Malaysia",
            "Myanmar"
        ],
        "name": {
            "en": "Thailand",
            "th": "ประเทศไทย"
        },
        "normalized_name": {
            "en": "thailand"
        }
    },
    {
        "country_code": "SG",
        "country_name": "Singapore",
        "currency_from": [
            "SGD",
            "USD"
        ],
        "currency_to": [
            "SGD"
        ],
        "popular_to": [
            "India",
            "United States"
        ],
        "name": {
            "en": "Singapore",
            "fr": "Singapour",
            "zh": "新加坡"
        },
        "normalized_name": {
            "en": "singapore"
        }
    }]
   }
   var currencydata = {
       currencies:[{
        "currency": "SGD",
        "country_code": "SG",
        "country_name": "Singapore",
        "name": {
            "en": "Singapore Dollar",
            "fr": "Dollar Singapour",
            "zh": "新加坡元"
        },
        "default_amount": "1000"
    },
    {
        "currency": "THB",
        "country_code": "TH",
        "country_name": "Thailand",
        "name": {
            "en": "Thailand Baht",
            "th": "เงินบาทไทย"
        },
        "default_amount": "9000"
    },
   }]}
   
   index.js file sample
   
   updateSendCountry(value) {
    this.sendvalue = this.countrydata.countries.filter(function (item) {
      return item.country_code == value;
    })
    if (this.sendvalue && this.sendvalue[0].currency_to) {
      var sendcurrency = this.sendvalue[0].currency_to[0];
      this.updateSendCurrency(sendcurrency);
    }
   }
    updateSendCurrency(e) {
    this.ccyvalue = this.currencydata.currencies.filter(function (item) {
      return item.currency == e;
    })
  }
   <select name="send_country" class="form-control" id="send_country" @change="${this.sendcountryChange}">
                           ${this.countrydata.countries.map((country, key) => html`<option value=${country.country_code}>${country.country_name}</option>`)}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group p-2">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <select name="sccy" class="form-control" id="sccy" @change="${this.updateSendCurrency}">
                          ${this.sendvalue.map((currency) => currency.currency_from.map((send) =>
                            html`<option value=${send}>${send}</option>`))
                          }                          
                         </select>
```

eg:

```
Dropdown A -> Singapore  populates Dropdown B -> SGD, USD
Dropdown A -> Thailand  populates Dropdown B -> THB, USD
if dropdown A selection shows Singapore, SGD USD in Dropdown B
if USD selected in Dropdown B then i change Dropdown A to thailand it Dropdow B 
populates THB, USB but shows USD first(second option) rather than THB
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.sendvalue.map(...)` is going to update the state (attributes and content) of the `<option>` elements, but it won't necessarily replace them. This means that when you change the list, the first option will have its text changed from `SGD` to `THB`, but the second option (`USD`) will still be selected.

If you want to control the selection state, you'll need to store it and use something like this for your item template:

```js
this.sendvalue.map((currency, index) => currency.currency_from.map((send) =>
    html`<option value=${send} ?selected=${index === selectedIndex}>${send}</option>`))
```

Here I'm using a variable `selectedIndex` to store the selected index. You'd have to reset it when changing the country.